# std::partition implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have already read about differences between std::partition and std::stable_partition.
Also I have watched the cppreference example

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::cout << "Original vector:\n    ";
    for(int elem : v) std::cout << elem << ' ';
 
    auto it = std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i){return i % 2 == 0;});
 
    std::cout << "\nPartitioned vector:\n    ";
}
```

> Original vector:
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> Partitioned vector:
> 0 8 2 6 4  *  5 3 7 1 9

But I'm still don't understand why in this example the order always the same.
All elements in the `std::vector` save in the heap, and iterator and address stability of elements is guaranteed with `std::vector` only if no reallocation takes place.
After std::partition this guarantee is violated, so the order can be different, but why it always *0 8 2 6 4*.

Or am I wrong and have a problem with memory visualisation of std::vector elements?

Comment: if the order can be anything then getting always the same order is a completely valid outcome. I don't see the problem. It rather would be strange if the algorithm yields different result for exact same input

Comment: what does it have to do with memory? The vector has same number of elements before and after, no reallocation is needed

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, it sounds logical, but it depends on works with memory, and then from complier type clang or gcc - because of difference memory visualisation. Then it random memory access then random elements should be in output sequence, where am i wrong?

Comment: @idclev463035818 "what does it have to do with memory?" well, why the order is not like in the `std::stable_partial`. I am trying to find answer on this question also,but no result.

Comment: no nothing about memory. Its about the values that are in the vector and implementation details of the algorithm. With a different implementation you might observe different order, but why you expect different outcome with one and the same implementation is unclear. "random access" does not mean that elements are accessed randomly

Comment: @Vladimir Not sure where you are wrong. What you say makes no sense to me. Why do you think order has anything to do with memory management in the first place?

Comment: is it "random access" that causes your confusion?

Comment: Because the implementation is deterministic.

Comment: @super because each element in the vector has a specific address in the memory

Comment: @M.A So, if we create a specific sequence that luckily gave us the sequence that will be sort, then in will be O(NlogN) , as you said deterministic set in the implementation. I'm trying to debug this code, but can't actually find where it determinate

Comment: @Vladimir Sure, but that doesn't mean that how the vector manages it underlying memory has anything to do with the order of the elements in it. Reallocating a vector never changes the order of the elements in it for example.

Comment: @super but in this example we did partition and the order was changes, why it was - yes, because of algorithm implementation, iterator compare usage but ... not absolutely understandable

Comment: The final order depends on the algorithm chosen by the library developers of the implementation you're using. The language standard doesn't require any specific order as long as the partitioning is correct. If you need to know the specifics then look at the code, it's all there in the header file(s).

Comment: without looking at any imlementation I would naively expect that two iterators are used one starting at begin, the other starting at end, then both are incremented/decremented until they hit an element that is in the wrong partition and they are swapped. Thats why you see that `1` and `8` swapped their position and `6` and `3` swapped their position. Thats one way to get the result as specified, but any other algorithm that partiontions the elements is as good

Comment: @idclev463035818 oh, yeah sound great! thank you

Comment: i was still guessing into the blue. It is quite unclear where your misunderstanding is. However, if you are fine with my last comment you should now look at the asnwer you got, because that is not just some guessing but code that is rather close to the actual implementation (its a "possible implementation" but close enough to the real one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the possible implementation from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) we can see its very deterministic (if the `UnaryPredicate` is deterministic).

```cpp
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate>
ForwardIt partition(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    first = std::find_if_not(first, last, p);
    if (first == last) return first;
 
    for (ForwardIt i = std::next(first); i != last; ++i) {
        if (p(*i)) {
            std::iter_swap(i, first);
            ++first;
        }
    }
    return first;
}
```

There is no question that it will do the same for the same input every time. The first two lines are only an optimization in case the source is somewhat partitioned.